# Post in jax rs jersey not working correctly

Tags: java, post, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

Here is Post method...

```
@Path("science")
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String postMultiple(Multiple getSuggestion) {
    Multiple postedQuestion = null;
    System.out.println(getSuggestion.getQuestion());
    System.out.println(getSuggestion.getOption1());
    System.out.println(getSuggestion.getOption2());
    System.out.println(getSuggestion.getOption3());
    System.out.println(getSuggestion.getAnswer());
    return "Post Works";
}
```

Here is Multiple Objects Definition...

You can see that i have made the class correctly

```
package in.webxstudio.rest.quiz.api.models;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;


@XmlRootElement
public class Multiple {
private String Question,Option1,Option2,Option3,Answer;


public Multiple() {}

public Multiple(String Question,String Option1,String Option2,String Option3,String Answer) {
        this.Question=Question;
        this.Option1=Option1;
        this.Option2=Option2;
        this.Option3=Option3;
        this.Answer=Answer;
    }


public String getQuestion() {
    return this.Question;
}
public String getOption1() {
    return this.Option1;
}
public String getOption2() {
    return this.Option2;
}
public String getOption3() {
    return this.Option3;
}
public String getAnswer() {
    return this.Answer;
}

public void setQuestion(String question) {
    this.Question = question;
}
public void setOption1(String option1) {
    this.Option1 = option1;
}
public void setOption2(String option2) {
    this.Option2 = option2;
}
public void setOption3(String option3) {
    this.Option3 = option3;
}
public void setAnswer(String answer) {
    this.Answer = answer;
}
}
```

But I am getting this output in my terminal / console

[image]

the input that I am posting at the api endpoint is as follows

```
{
  "answer": "Blue Whale",
  "option1": "Orca",
  "option2": "Colossal Squid",
  "option3": "Giraffe",
  "question": "What is the largest animal currently on Earth?"
}
```

Can anybody say what am I doing wrong here.?
How can i correct this behavior

Comment: Show `Multiple` object definitons

Comment: Just Posted an update @user7294900

Comment: Please use Java naming convention: variable names start with lower case.

Comment: In POST body you are passing lowercase letters, but in `Multiple` class variables are camelcase, change them to lowercase as in POST body

Comment: without any changes i'm getting correct output

Comment: after making the changes below i was able to get correct output earlier only null came as output answer that @PaulSamsotha  suggested is right

Comment: @KathirvelSubramanian Most likely difference in JSON providers. With Jackson, the setter will be called. In this case the setter still follows Java bean convention and so matches the lower case JSON. Maybe with a different provider like MOXy, the field names are used for matching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always Follow Java's Variable Naming Conventions Such as 
Variable names should Start with a lowercase Letter..

```
public class Multiple {
private String question,option1,option2,option3,answer;


public Multiple() {}

public Multiple(String question,String option1,String option2,String option3,String answer) {
    this.question=question;
    this.option1=option1;
    this.option2=option2;
    this.option3=option3;
    this.answer=answer;
}


public String getQuestion() {
    return this.question;
}
public String getOption1() {
    return this.option1;
}
public String getOption2() {
    return this.option2;
}
public String getOption3() {
    return this.option3;
}
public String getAnswer() {
    return this.answer;
}

public void setQuestion(String question) {
    this.question = question;
}
public void setOption1(String option1) {
    this.option1 = option1;
}
public void setOption2(String option2) {
    this.option2 = option2;
}
public void setOption3(String option3) {
    this.option3 = option3;
}
public void setAnswer(String answer) {
    this.answer = answer;
}
}
```